# Configure apiserver to use encryption config using minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to configure the `kube-apiserver` so that it uses encryption to configure secrets in my minikube cluster.

For that, I have followed the [documentation on kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/#encrypting-your-data) but got stuck at step 3 that says

*Set the `--encryption-provider-config` flag on the `kube-apiserver` to point to the location of the config file.*

I have discovered the option `--extra-config` on `minikube start` and have tried starting my setup using

`minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.encryption-provider-config=encryptionConf.yaml`

but naturally it doesn't work as `encryptionConf.yaml` is located in my local file system and not in the pod that's spun up by minikube. The error `minikube log` gives me is

`error: error opening encryption provider configuration file "encryptionConf.yaml": open encryptionConf.yaml: no such file or directory`

What is the best practice to get the encryption configuration file onto the `kube-apiserver`? Or is `minikube` perhaps the wrong tool to try out these kinds of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2741#issuecomment-398683171) where they have a similar issue for passing a configuration file. The comment that helped me was the slightly hacky solution that made use of the fact that the directory `/var/lib/localkube/certs/` from the minikube VM is mounted into the apiserver.

So my final solution was to run

```
minikube mount .:/var/lib/minikube/certs/hack
```

where in the current directory I had my `encryptionConf.yaml` and then start minikube like so

```
minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.encryption-provider-config=/var/lib/minikube/certs/hack/encryptionConf.yaml
```

Comment: This could be a loaded follow up but anyone that has access to this encryptionConf.yaml essentially could decode the base 64 in there to reveal your secret correct?  Or, once you start minikube with this way, can you delete the conf file?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on drivers used some directories are mounted on to your minikube VM.
Check this link - https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#mounted-host-folders

Also ~/.minikube/files is also mounted into the VM at /files. So you can keep your files there and use that path for API server config

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I managed to mount the file and can verify that it's there when I ssh into the minikube VM. However, I still can't access it from the `kube-apiserver` pod, as it's not mounted there - still gives me the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues in windows regarding filepath location
since C:\Users\%USERNAME%\ is by default mounted in minikube VM
so i copied the files to Desktop folder( any folder under **C drive** )

```
minikube --extra-config=apiserver.encryption-provider-config=/c/Users/%USERNAME%/.../<file-name>
```

hope this is helpful for folks facing this issues on windows platform.